# Zoom in TeeChart HTML5/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, zooming, teechart

I'm testing a new TeeChart HTML5/javascript and I have a problem with zoom.
When I apply the zoom several times, the navigator crash.
Occurs too with the code in "demos" folder.
I'm testing with a line chart, but the bar chart applies zoom too. 
It's possible see here: http://steema.us/joomla25

Any idea? Someone also noted ?
Thanks!

Comment: Apply smaller zoom, several times. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce it zooming in again and again. I've added it to the defect list.
Thanks for reporting it.

--

Best Regards,

Yeray Alonso

Steema Support Central

Comment: We've just fixed it. Please, write to "info at steema dot com" asking for the fixed TeeChart.js

Comment: Ok. I will check in future versions. I need this corrected function to use it in my app. Thanks!